# Error Converting data type 'Numeric' to Decimal (help!)

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

Good Day Everyone,

As of now im stuck with this error

```
Error Converting data type 'Numeric' to Decimal
```

this is my code

```
AddManualItems AddReconItem = new AddManualItems();
        UserAccess user = new UserAccess();
        AddReconItem.BranchCode = BranchCodeTextBox.Text;
        AddReconItem.ForLoanMonth = YearDropDownList.SelectedValue + "/" + MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        AddReconItem.ItemWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(WeightTextBox.Text);     
        AddReconItem.PrincipalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(PrincipalTexAmTextBox.Text);
        AddReconItem.PawnTicket = PwnTicketTextBox.Text;
        AddReconItem.ItemStorageGroup = Convert.ToInt16(StorageNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        AddReconItem.ReconID = Convert.ToInt16(ReconTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        user.UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();

        string a = servs.AddItemRecon(user, AddReconItem); // this is where the error appears in debug mode
```

the code inside of the ADDitemRecon(User,AddReconItem) is this

```
 using (SqlConnection reportsConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnWriter))
            {
                reportsConn.Open();
                SqlCommand AddReconItem = new SqlCommand();
                AddReconItem.Connection = reportsConn;
                AddReconItem.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                AddReconItem.CommandText = "Updater.usp_AddReconcileItems";
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEMWEIGHT", Convert.ToDecimal( items.ItemWeight));
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEMPRINCIPALAMT", Convert.ToDecimal(items.PrincipalAmount));
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORLOANMONTH", Convert.ToDateTime(items.ForLoanMonth));
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STORAGEGROUPID", items.ItemStorageGroup);
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRANCHCODE", items.BranchCode);
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("RECONID", items.ReconID);
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAWNTIX",items.PawnTicket);
                AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATEDBY", user.UserID.ToString());
                AddReconItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

my property for ItemWeight is

```
 private decimal itemWeight;

    public decimal ItemWeight
    {
        get { return itemWeight; }
        set { itemWeight = value; }
    }
```

i bet the error is in the item weight because when i input in the item weight
12345.12 it works fine, but when i input 1234 instead of treating it as 1234.00 it treats it as 1234 only making it numeric..

any help? i do not know if my conversions are wrong

By the way my field in database is

```
fld_ItemWeight (decimal (38,6), not null
```

EDIT**
Is there any bugs known in Decimal?? im using VS 2005 as of now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found The answer! my stored Procedure is wrong i have decimal(9,6) in my stored procedured making it accept 3 digits or less !changed it to (18,2)\

Answer (score 7):

Although the original poster has found his solution, for the benefit of other people, I thought I would post what caused it for me.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Error converting data type numeric to decimal.

Sadly the message doesn't say which parameter it is having the problem with. So I changed all of the parameters that I was passing through to have a value of 0 (which is a suitable value for most SQL types, you may need to use other values), this made the error go away. I could then put them back to normal, one by one, and each time, I re-tested. That's how I worked out which parameter had the problem.

It turned out that for one of the parameters the **value** that I had in my code (a C# decimal) was too large to go in the decimal(7,2) stored procedure parameter.

Comment: just a reminder, (7,2) decimal  means 7 is the length of the whole decimal and 2 of those is decimal, meaning to say your whole value will only consist of 5 numbers and 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the proper solution for this issue , But i have one idea. Like

Change your `ItemWeight` property `DataType` decimal to string

```
  decimal xxxyyy = Convert.ToDecimal(WeightTextBox.Text); 

    if(!xxxyyy .ToString().Contains(".00))
    {
      AddReconItem.ItemWeight=xxxyyy.ToString() +".00";
    }
    else
    {
     AddReconItem.ItemWeight=xxxyyy.ToString() ;
    }
```

Edit :

Try this another way for use `math.Round()`

```
AddReconItem.ItemWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(WeightTextBox.Text);    
AddReconItem.ItemWeight=Math.Round(AddReconItem.ItemWeight,2);
```

Comment: already tried but no luck, when converting to Decimal any 00 after the . is removed and i dont know why i just saw it in debug mode

Comment: a 112345.00 when converted returns 112345 that's the values that is being passed in the database and thats where the exception occurs maybe

Comment: @DanzaiVer Change your database column DataType decimal to nvarchar and try my solution .

Comment: if i do that what's the essence of decimal datatype? i know it would work but my database will suffer from retrieval of data expecially if i need to sum them all because i need to convert them first into decimal before i can sum them.

Comment: @DanzaiVer Okay leave that , see My Updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

Try to round your value in set.

private decimal itemWeight;

```
public decimal ItemWeight
{
    get { return itemWeight; }
    set { itemWeight = Math.Round(value,yourPrecisionHere); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Sql column to Decimal(18,2), Same in store procedure and take SqlDbType.Decimal at ado.net end

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the column had the right precision and scale(16,2) but the variable I was using as a parameter in the procedure hadn't(14,2).
So, when trying to insert something like 99999999999999 using the procedure, I was getting the error **Error converting data type numeric to numeric**.

Answer (score -1):

when you are calling a procedure and it has a parameter with a decimal datatype then you can pass only in fractions. For more details please refer [Error converting data type numeric to decimal](http://mattclingan.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/error-converting-data-type-numeric-to-decimal/)

Comment: decimal (38,6) i have this, based on the articled you have given this should not generate any errors, fractions are only applicable to those who has a declaration of (2,2) same precision and same number of decimals allowed.